# How to animate a png sequence with core animation in cocoa (not touch)

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I would like to animate a png sequence in a NSImageView, but I cannot make it work. It just does not want to show any animation. Any suggestion?

This is my code:

```
- (void) imageAnimation {
  NSMutableArray *iconImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (int i=0; i<=159; i++) {
    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%05d",@"clear",i];
    [iconImages addObject:(id)[NSImage imageNamed:imagePath]];
    //NSImage *iconImage = [NSImage imageNamed:imagePath];
    //[iconImages addObject:(__bridge id)CGImageCreateWithNSImage(iconImage)];
  }


  CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
  CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
  [animation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationDiscrete];
  [animation setDuration:10.0f];
  [animation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
  [animation setValues:iconImages];

  [layer setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 104, 104)];
  layer.bounds = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 104, 104);
  [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];

  //Add to the NSImageView layer
  [iconV.layer addSublayer:layer];
}
```

Comment: What is happening? Is nothing showing or is only the first image showing? (This may be a stupid question) Is your image view layer-backed? (Have you called [iconV setWantsLayer:YES];?)

Comment: Now, it works! that was easy. I did't use  [iconV setWantsLayer:YES] I wasn't aware of it. Please put your comment as an answer and I will accept it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

Make your view layer-hosting by calling

```
[iconV setLayer:[CALayer layer]];
[iconV setWantsLayer:YES];
```

---

### Why nothing happens

The reason nothing is happening is that your image view doesn't have a layer so when you call `[iconV.layer addSublayer:layer];` you are sending a message to `nil` and nothing happens (the sublayer is not added to the image view).

Views on OS X don't use Core Animation layers as their backing store by default for backwards compatibility. A view with a layer can either be *layer-backed* or *layer-hosting*.

You should not interact directly with a layer-*backed* view and you shouldn't add *views* (but adding layers is ok) to a layer-*hosting* view. Since you are adding the layer to your image views layer (and thus interacting directly with it) you want a layer-hosting view.

### Fixing it

You can tell your view that it should be layer-hosting by first giving it the layer using `[iconV setLayer:[CALayer layer]];` and then (order is important) telling it that it wants a layer using `[iconV setWantsLayer:YES];`.

For more information on layer-backed and layer-hosting views please read [the documentation for `wantsLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer:).

Comment: I think that if you want to manipulate a view's layer then the layer must be explicitly assigned, e.g. `view.layer = [CALayer layer];`. `setWantsLayer:` tells the view to create a layer for its own usages. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer:

Comment: True. That makes it a layer-hosting view. (It's even bold in the documentation).. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but I will post my solution because the original one plus the answer posted by @David did not work for me. I am creating on Xcode 8.3.3, compiling for 10.10.

What did not work for me was to create the layer separately and then set the image view with it.

**this did not work for me**

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
layer.bounds = self.imageView.bounds;
[self.imageView setLayer:layer];
```

The result was always no animation.

Apparently, on 10.10, when you do this:

```
self.imageView.wantsLayer = YES;
```

MacOS creates a layer and assigns it to the image view.

So, the code that **worked for me** was:

```
self.imageView.wantsLayer = YES;

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
[animation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationDiscrete];
[animation setDuration:1.3f];
[animation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
[animation setValues:imageArray];
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];  
[self.imageView setAnimates:YES];

[self.imageView setCanDrawSubviewsIntoLayer:YES];
```

This last line is very important. If you remove that it will not show any image!