# NSImageView animations

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to Mac development, Do we have any methods like 
                   **imagev = [NSArray arrayWithObjects**

I need some thing like what we do in iOS want to do in mac,

```
imageVie.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"] ,nil];
```

In iPhone, How can i animate

Regards

Comment: I think you're missing half of what you wanted to post...

Comment: I need some thing like what we do in iOS want to do in mac,imageVie.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"] ,nil];

Comment: @kiri: So, you want to take a series of images, make a single animated image from them, and display that in an image view, on the Mac?

Answer (score 4):

I found someone using a [Core Animation approach to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13011527/449161) which was close enough for me. I modified it slightly. You need to `@import QuartzCore;`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    NSMutableArray *spinnerImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:30u];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"spinner%@", @(i)];
        [spinnerImages addObject:[NSImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    }
    self.spinnerImages = spinnerImages;
    layer.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
    [self.imageView setLayer:layer]; // This view is just a container for the layer. Its frame can be managed by a xib.
    self.imageView.wantsLayer = YES;

    self.spinnerLayer = layer;
}
```

Then you can animate it like this:

```
- (void)stopAnimating
{
    if ([self.layer.animationKeys containsObject:kAnimationKey])
    {
        [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:kAnimationKey];
    }
}

- (void)startAnimating
{
    if ([self.layer.animationKeys containsObject:kAnimationKey])
    {
        return;
    }
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kAnimationKey];
    [animation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationDiscrete];
    [animation setDuration:1.0f];
    [animation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    [animation setValues:self.spinnerImages];
    [self.spinnerLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];
}
```

Comment: Was trying to use a simple timer to replace images, which result in CPU around 90%. Using CoreAnimation reduce it close to ~1%.

Comment: Is there a way to animate my sequence only once so that the last frame remains?

Answer (score 2):

Building on the great answer by **Ben Flynn**.

In Swift 3:

```
// This needs to happen around init.
// NSView (and who inherit from it) does not come with a layer.
// self.layer will be nil at init.
self.layer = CALayer()
self.wantsLayer = true

let layer = CALayer()
let keyPath = "contents" // (I did not find a constant for that key.)
let frameAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)
frameAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete

// Duration
// This is the duration of one cycle
let durationOfAnimation: CFTimeInterval = 2.5
frameAnimation.duration = durationOfAnimation
frameAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE// can also use Float.infinity

let imageSeq: [NSImage] = imageSequance // Your images to animate
frameAnimation.values = imageSeq

// Sadly, there are no layout constraints on CALayer.
// If your view will be resized while animating, you'll need to override
// 'func layout()' and calculate aspect ratio if needs be
let layerRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.frame.size)
layer.frame = layerRect
layer.bounds = layerRect
layer.add(frameAnimation, forKey: keyPath)

self.layer?.addSublayer(layer)
```

---

If the view is expected to be resized:

Remove these lines:

```
let layerRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.frame.size)
layer.frame = layerRect
layer.bounds = layerRect
```

And call `self.needsLayout = true` after adding the sublayer. This will cause the `layout()` to be called.

```
//let layerRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.frame.size)
//layer.frame = layerRect
//layer.bounds = layerRect
layer.add(frameAnimation, forKey: keyPath)

self.layer?.addSublayer(layer)
self.needsLayout = true
```

Lastly, override `layout()`:

```
override func layout() {
    super.layout()

    var layerFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.frame.size)
    self.myLayer.frame = layerFrame
    self.myLayer.bounds = // Adjust ratio as needed.
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to animate my sequence only once so that the last frame remains?

Comment: What I did was to schedule a timer to fire at the end of the animation (that is the animation duration number) and remove the animation layer. At that point you simply present a selected image. Some CoreAnimation allow to either 'rewind' of leave animation on last frame on end, but I did not see such option on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa doesn't have anything like `animatedImageWithImages:duration:`. Images in Cocoa can vary in space (different resolutions) and color depth, but not time; a single image is always a static image, never animated.

(There *might* be an exception for animated GIFs, but GIFs can't display more than 255 or 256 colors per frame, and do not support partial transparency. Moreover, I haven't tried creating or displaying GIFs using the NSImage or CGImage machinery.)

What you'll need to do is create not an image, but a movie. [Add images to the movie, varying each one's duration to achieve the playback speed you want.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/QTMovie/addImage%3aforDuration%3awithAttributes%3a) Then, display your movie in a [movie view](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovieView_Class/), optionally with [the controller hidden](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovieView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/QTMovieView/setControllerVisible%3a).

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

I couldn’t get the previous answers get to work until I added a `beginTime`. Since `Swift 3` some constants changed too. So I’ve converted the solution to `Swift 4.2`. Also, I thought it would be handy to create it as a `CALayer` extention:

```
extension CALayer {  

static func image(sequence: [NSImage], duration: CFTimeInterval? = nil, frame: CGRect? = nil) -> CALayer {

    let layer = CALayer()
    if let f = frame { layer.frame = f }
    layer.autoresizingMask = [.layerWidthSizable, .layerHeightSizable]

    let keyPath = "contents"

    let keyFrameAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)
    keyFrameAnimation.values = sequence
    keyFrameAnimation.calculationMode = .discrete
    keyFrameAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    keyFrameAnimation.duration = duration ?? CFTimeInterval(sequence.count / 18)
    keyFrameAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    keyFrameAnimation.autoreverses = false
    keyFrameAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    keyFrameAnimation.beginTime = 0.0

    layer.add(keyFrameAnimation, forKey: keyPath)

    return layer

}
}
```

Use it like

```
let sequenceLayer = CALayer.image(sequence: imageSequence, duration: 0.55, frame: yourView.bounds)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface AnimatedNSImage : NSImage

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBInspectable NSImageView         *delegate;

    @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray                         *frames;
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat                         duration;

    - (instancetype) initWithImages:(NSArray*)frames duration:(CGFloat)duration;

@end
```

And in the .m file...

```
@interface AnimatedNSImage () {

    NSTimer                         *_scheduledTimer;
    NSArray                         *_frames;

    NSUInteger                      _frameIndex;
    CGFloat                         _duration;

}

@end

@implementation AnimatedNSImage

    @synthesize delegate;

    - (NSArray *) frames
    {
        return _frames;
    }

    - (CGImageRef) CGImage
    {
        if (_frames && _frames.count >0) {
            NSImage *_frame = _frames[_frameIndex];
            return _frame.CGImage;
        }
        return nil;
    }

    - (NSArray<NSImageRep *> *) representations
    {
        NSImage *_frame = _frames[_frameIndex];
        return _frame.representations;
    }

    - (CGFloat) duration
    {
        return _duration;
    }

    - (void) __showNextFrame:(id)sender
    {
        _frameIndex = (_frameIndex + 1) % _frames.count;
        if (delegate) {
            [delegate setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        }
    }

    - (NSSize) size
    {
        if (_frames && _frames.count >0) {
            NSImage *_frame = _frames[_frameIndex];
            return _frame.size;
        }
        return CGSizeZero;
    }

    - (void) setup
    {
        _scheduledTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_duration target:self selector:@selector(__showNextFrame:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    - (void) dealloc
    {
        [_scheduledTimer invalidate];
        _scheduledTimer = nil;
    }

    - (instancetype) initWithImages:(NSArray *)frames duration:(CGFloat)duration
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _frames = frames;
            _duration = duration / 100.0f;
            [self setup];
        }
        return self;
    }

@end
```

Note that you will have to assign the delegate (to the NSImageView) in order to invoke a refresh..

An example....

```
IBOutlet NSImageView *_testGifView;

AnimatedNSImage *_animatedImage = [NSImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://media.giphy.com/media/B2zB8mHrHHUXS57Cuz/giphy.gif"]];
_testGifView.image = _animatedImage;        
_animatedImage.delegate = _testGifView;
```

The scheduled timer of course can be adjusted as required as the input time is in centiseconds (as opposed to minutes).